# What's the maximum compression of the spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I  tried to use the conservation of energy to solve this problem, here's what I tried to do:

$\require{enclose}$
$$\begin{align}
\enclose{downdiagonalstrike} {\frac{1}{2}} m v^{2} &= \enclose{downdiagonalstrike} {\frac{1}{2}}Kx^{2} \\[1em] 
m v^{2}&=K x^{2} \\[1em]
\frac{m v^{2}}{K}&=x^{2} \\
x&=\sqrt{\frac{m v^{2}}{K}}
\end{align}$$

> A block of mass M is initially at rest on a frictionless floor, as shown in the accompanying figure. The block, attached to a massless spring with spring constant k, is initially at its equilibrium position. An arrow with mass m and velocity v is shot into the block The arrow sticks in the block. What is the maximum compression of the spring?

The correct answer is E, but I need someone to explain it

> [image]
>
> - A) $x=v \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$
> - B) $x=v \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$
> - C) $x=v \sqrt{\frac{m+M}{k}}$
> - D) $x=\frac{(m+M) v}{\sqrt{m k}}$
> - E) $x=\frac{m v}{\sqrt{(m+M) k}}$

Comment: Can you provide your attempt to a solution and/or your thoughts?

Comment: I tried to use the conservation of energy to solve this problem but it didn't work though

Comment: That seems like a valid approach. You should edit the question to fully describe your line of thinking and your complete solution, so that we can fully address your question.

Comment: I have edited the post nw

Comment: It looks like your answer is the same as (b). I think you are correct.

Comment: nop, the correct answer is E. but I need to know why

Answer (score 3):

You forgot about conservation of momentum in your formula so momentum before collision is $m.v$ and after collision is $(m+M)v_2$ by conservation of momentum $v_2=\frac{m.v}{m+M}$ since arrow stuck to the system new mass is$m+M$ substituting these in conservation of energy you get your E answer